# arcpy.da.UpdateCursor with SQL query

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, sql, cursor

I am having issues with my SQL query in the `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`. The code seems to work fine if I remove the SQL query  so I am fairly certain that it is the issue. The syntax that I would use in ArcMap is `last_edited_date >= GETDATE() AND last_edited_user NOT LIKE 'ESRI'`. How do I write this in Python?

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Define Variables
fc = r'C:\Users\...\FSAArchiveTest.gdb\FSA_Archive_Test'

try:

    edited_archive = "last_edited_archive" #This is a STRING field
    edited_user = "last_edited_user"  #This is a STRING field
    edited_date = "last_edited_date" #This is a DATE field


    #THIS IS THE SQL QUERY THAT IS NOT WORKING 
    sql = "last_edited_date >= GETDATE() AND last_edited_user NOT LIKE {0}".format('ESRI')

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,[edited_archive, edited_user, edited_date], sql) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:

            row[0] = (row[1] + " " + str(row[2]))
            cursor.updateRow(row)

        print("It worked")

except:

    print("did not work")
```

Comment: The `LIKE` operator is the wrong tool for a simple equivalence test (without wildcard character), but all you need to do is add single quotes before/after the `{0}` -- `'{0}'` *or* put double-quotes around the formatted term -- `"'ESRI'"`. If in doubt, print the SQL string and paste it in a SQL browser.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! Should I use <> for the equivalence test instead?

Comment: For a simple string test, yes: `sql = "last_edited_date >= GETDATE() AND last_edited_user <> 'ESRI'"` though this may only find rows edited in the future (depending on the SQL engine).